# Can the restrictive "ne ... que ..." qualify a conditional clause like "correctement utilisé" without "si"?

Tags: grammaire

In conversation, I just said:

> L'argent n'a de sens que **correctement utilisé**.

In hindsight, though, I'm not sure if this structure is grammatical. A *conditional* clause like "correctement utilisé" without "si/quand" is usually used, as in:

> (S'il / Quand il est) **Correctement utilisé**, l'argent peut vous ouvrir bien des portes.

Can the restrictive "ne ... que ..." qualify this conditional clause without "si/quand"? I think I'm so used to the structure "ne ... que **si**/**quand** ..." that the omission of "si/quand" after "que" subconsciously struck me as odd.

Even if it is grammatical, I wonder if it is seen as rather formal in register?

Answer (score 3):

Oui. C'est une omission possible de « l'argent n'a de sens que [s'il est] correctement utilisé.

Ce n'est pas particulièrement formel, mais l'omission n'est pas complètement évidente, d'autant plus que dans « … n'a de sens que … », on aurait d'abord tendance à associer ce qui suit « que » au sens et non à l'argent. Du coup, l'omission me paraît naturelle à l'écrit, mais moins à l'oral.